# Camel splitter returns ExpressionNode

Tags: java, apache-camel, dsl

I have route:

```
    from(SU_NAME)
        .choice()
            .when(STATUS_IS_OK)
                .to("xslt:xsl/RemoveNode.xsl")
                    .split().tokenizeXML("Event", "Header").to(XP_NAME)
            .otherwise()
                .dynamicRouter(method(router, "slip"))
    .end();
```

If I remove splitter I have everything working fine, but having it in my route gives me:

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method otherwise() is undefined for the type ExpressionNode
```

I need splitter to be part of the route, can you help me. I understand that there should be choise ChoiceDefinition not ExpressionNode, not how can I modify code to get this.

Answer (score 3):

See this FAQ - Why can I not use when/otherwise in a Java Camel route?
http://camel.apache.org/why-can-i-not-use-when-or-otherwise-in-a-java-camel-route.html

Comment: .to(XP_NAME).endChoice() helped. The interesting part is that I know this article, and more interesting part is that I have implemented much more complex routes using endChoises right in this project :) But this route suddenly made me feel like: "I don't know how to do this". Really, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it appears that your "split" isn't terminated. Try this:

```
from(SU_NAME)
    .choice()
        .when(STATUS_IS_OK)
            .to("xslt:xsl/RemoveNode.xsl")
            .split().tokenizeXML("Event", "Header")
                .to(XP_NAME)
            .end() /* <-- explicitly end the split here, that should help */
        .otherwise()
            .dynamicRouter(method(router, "slip"))
     .end();
```

Comment: no, this is not working, putting .endChoise() helped, and tests are good, but for more complex routes, endchoise is destroying actual flow (I have lots of route test failures)

Comment: I used one more technique for resolving cast problems: chaining with direct, and it helped. But looks like, the better way is is moving to xml dsl